# How can I serialize sequential access to a resource in a threaded server application?

Tags: multithreading, rust, lazy-evaluation, rust-tokio

I'm writing a `rust` application that binds to a TCP/IP port and asynchronously spins up a stream handler for the connected sockets using `tokio::spawn`.  I would like to handle multiple connections to the socket and serialize sequential access to a resource, say, I²C: the order of the sequences don't matter, but they should be atomic.

I'm not sure what mechanisms are available in `rust` for this sort of thing and was wondering if using [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) would my best course of action.

My thinking with `lazy_static` would be to declare a global variable for the bus, and have the spawned methods access the bus through that global static.

Does this approach make sense? As long as I don't have an `.await` in the methods that take ownership of the bus, I should be okay, no?

Comment: One way would be to wrap your resource in an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` which you keep locked during access. Another way would be to spawn a single thread to operate on the common resource and use `channels` to request operations from this thread and send the results back to your connection tasks.

Comment: No your approach with a global is unsound even if you don't `await` because Tokio may run tasks on multiple threads.

Comment: @Jmb I'm curious; why when using a Mutex would one need the resource counter wrapped around it?